# Why port 22 redirection causes lxc containers to ssh to host?

Tags: debian, iptables, lxc

I have a host A on which I have 2 lxc container (X and Y).

I originally had port 22 on my host (A) forwarded to X. Using this configuration, I wasn't able to ssh out of the container X and when ssh-ing out of contianer Y, it caused the ssh connection to be some how forwarded to X (even though I was ssh-in to an external computer).

When changing the port 22 fowarding from the host to forwarding port 2222 to X:22 then everything went back to normal...

Is there a way to forward port 22 to an lxc container?

Iptables command I used to forward port 22 on host A to container X:

> iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.4 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
>
> iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.4:22

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed by adding the `-i eth0` to my iptable rules (to specify only outside traffic should be redirected to container X:22.

> iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 22 -i eth0 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.4:22

Comment: In my case, I had to add `-i ens3`. Just prepare to use the correct interface.